How to generate .tflite models form Qualcomm AI Hub Models
I have a Qualcomm device and I want to deploy LLMs on it. I want to get .tflite model. I downloaded an Android app from Google AI which can deploy tensorflow lite models, while it only accepts .tflite file. And I cannot find a website to directly download .tflite model files
I followed the instructions here, and in the end it says the model can be .tflite exported. But I don't know how to get .tflite model files.
Qualcomm AI Hub provides LLMs models that specially modified for specific devices. And I followed instructions here.
I ran command below to learn the usages, but no options like --target-runting tflite.
python -m qai_hub_models.models.llama_v2_7b_chat_quantized.export -h

Then I ran the command below, and only .bin models are downloaded.
python -m qai_hub_models.models.llama_v2_7b_chat_quantized.export --device "XR2 Gen 2 (Proxy)"

Can someone helps me to get LLM files of .tflite type?

The LLMs are currently not support on TensorFlow Lite with NPU acceleration using the delegate. This is primarily because of 2 reasons:

The delegates are "runtime compiled" which means the actual compilation of the .tflite model to the hardware is done when the model is loaded. LLM compilation can take several minutes and doing that at first load is not usually feasible. Most LLMs today are deployed using compilation ahead of time. That infra is currently being worked on for TensorFlow Lite.
Protobuf has a 2GB limit and many of these models are > than that. Some infra is needed to make TensorFlow Lite compatible with that.

To get an LLM working today, you have to use the QNN APIs (Qualcomm AI Engine Direct) or ONNX Runtime (which has an ahead of time compile path)
